# Pushing outputObject to JSON file in Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

Have a requirement of pushing outputObject which is a result of accessibility violations to JSON file in Playwright.

The code below is in protractor but need to migrate it to Playwright.

```
import { Page } from 'playwright-core';
import { AxeCoreResult, AxeCoreViolation, AxeCoreViolationNode } from './axe-core-result';
  const outputObject: AxeCoreResult = {
    description,
    ignoreViolations,
    violations: violationsOutput,
  };

  if (ignoreViolations) {
    browser.params.axecoreE2eExpectedFailures.push(outputObject);
  }
```

Here, AxeCoreResult is an interface with properties being defined.In the line where browser.params is used, facing error while migrating the same to Playwright. Any inputs on this would be helpful.

Tried using different browser options for Playwright like newContext() but couldn't resolve it.
Expectation: should push the outputObject to json file.

Comment: What is the error and stacktrace?